# postgresql select to show only values without hyphen

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im using postgres 11 i want to make a select statment to not show values with hyphen:

```
 date                       | name
 2020-10-06 10:07:42.706231 | Honda
 2020-09-13 08:29:52.150221 | Honda
 2020-10-01 08:25:08        | Honda-78391957
 2020-09-13 08:29:49.971063 | Kawasaki
 2020-10-01 08:26:29.272186 | Honda
 2020-10-01 08:25:11        | Kawasaki-05691
```

so my query will return only:

```
 date                       | name
 2020-10-06 10:07:42.706231 | Honda
 2020-09-13 08:29:52.150221 | Honda
 2020-09-13 08:29:49.971063 | Kawasaki
 2020-10-01 08:26:29.272186 | Honda
```

And leave out the values with hyphen.

I didn't find anything online only ways to ignore it(show the value without the hyphen like Kawasaki05691) or catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try with

```
    select date, name
    from the_table where name not like '%-%'
```

so you will leave those records out..
You can also take a look at postgresql doc:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

```
   select date, replace(name,'-','') as name
   from the_table
```

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * from items WHERE NOT (name like '%-%');`